# Image format and size recommended for Windows8 / Windows-Phone-8 game development?

Tags: windows-8, svg, windows-phone-8, screen-resolution, image-formats

Background info:
I am just starting to develop my first Silverlight/ c# game for the new W8 WP8 Systems.
And I want to do the Basics correct from the start.

I do not want to run into Problems with the different devices and resolutions which will be
available, ending up with a lot of Images I would need at the end for the different Screen sizes & resolutions of such devices.

So I thought to do the whole Imaging in incscape and create svg Images.
But there seems to be no easy way to integrate svg Images or xaml code I generate, which is not hard coded.

Concrete Question:
My question would be, which strategy for the Image format would you recommend, whe taking care on a bunch of different Screen resolutions and devices like low cost WP8 phones or highend tablets?

Are Vector Graphics (SVG, XAML) a real alternative or do I just have to take care of just a few different resolutions for my png Images when I want to develop a game which will work on WP8 and as a Metro App on Win 8 as well?

Thanks for any hints you can give me on this or any direction you can Show me.

Daniel

Comment: This MSDN article provides the information you need to know about the types of resolutions supported on a Windows Phone 8 device: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974(v=vs.105).aspx